# Link annotation different between Adobe reader and Acrobat professional

Tags: luatex, tagged-pdf, tagpdf

I generate the Website text PDF using tagpdf command. I am getting two different visual while touch link contents in Adobe Reader and Acrobat Professional. In this problem in all type of link text.

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}

\DeclareDocumentMetadata{testphase=phase-III}

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tagpdf}

\usepackage{hyperref}%

\begin{document}

\href{www.google.com}{Google Link}

\end{document}
```

Adobe Reader Output:

[image]

Acrobat Professional Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your link syntax is wrong. You are missing the protocol

```
\href{https://www.google.com}{Google Link}
```

The tagging code is not needed to insert links, that is done by hyperref.

Your document also shows outdated method to load the PDF management and the tagging code. In a current LaTeX (and if you want to work with tagging you should ensure that you have a current TeX system!) it is no longer needed to load pdfmanagement-testphase manually, and the starting command changed to `\DocumentMetadata`. The tagging code should be loaded with the testphase key.

```
\DocumentMetadata{testphase=phase-III}

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}%

\begin{document}

\href{https://www.google.com}{Google Link}

\end{document}
```

But beside this I can't reproduce your problem. Both adobe reader and adobe acrobat show the same pop up (which can't be change by the latex code, it is the viewer which decided how to show links).

Comment: Now, its working fine. Thank you.

Comment: But the document not Tagged the PDF.

Comment: it is tagged https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHhqD.png